# how to get the short codes?

Tags: java, android

how to get the short codes from a service providers? 
I want to create a app that could receve these sms sent to the short codes by the user and the app should return the response to the client.

Answer (score -1):

You need a suitable sms gateway. Like this two german sites:

- [smstrade.de](http://www.smstrade.de/index.php?select=empfang)
- [smskaufen.com](http://www.smskaufen.com/sms/index.php?seite=smsin)